# Css transition not applying in child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm currently facing the following problem.
I have a `<section>` element that has some `<div>` as children.
The height of the `<section>` is set as a percentage of the parent div, and the `<div>`'s height is also set as a percentage of the `<section>`.

I'm using Jquery to add a class to the `<section>` in order to transition between two heights. The problem is that the children aren't updating their height.

I don't want to refresh the css using ye olde `display: none` and `removeAttr("style")` trick since I want the transition to be applied to the children too.

I've made a couple of sketches to help understand the problem.

Initial state
[image: Initial state]
After the transition
[image: After the transition]

- EDIT

The `<section>` tag has the following classes at initial state:
`fullWidth halfHeight expandableTransition`

```
.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.halfHeight {
  height: 48%;
}

.expandableTransition {
  -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: height 1s;
}
```

The CSS for the children `<div>` is:

```
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 82%;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The class added by Jquery in order to transition to the new height is as simple as:

```
.expandedSection {
  height: 96%;
}
```

The Jquery code that adds the class is the following:

```
function expandSection() {
    $("#prioritySection").toggleClass("expandedSection");
}
```

Comment: And your code is ....

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes, sorry about that, I'll just add it right now.

Comment: Ok, I wait for that :) You can provide a jsfiddle.net because is easier

Comment: @RameezRami Ok, I'll see what I can do about that. What I'm getting with this is that it should be transitioning and my HTML structure is bugging it up.
The HTML structure is a bit more complex than the sketches I'll give you that.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Ah! I didn't think about that! :) I'll get to it. I've posted the code meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using bit more classes for animation

i hope this helps

fiddle goes here https://jsfiddle.net/rameezrami/1axvcoeh/3/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;background: green;
  height: 48%;
}

.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 82%;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: red;
}

.expandedSection {
  height: 96%;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: height 1s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="fullWidth">

<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
</section>
<input type="button" onclick="expandSection();" value="click to expand">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function expandSection() {
    $(".fullWidth").toggleClass("expandedSection");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, that's a nice fiddle right there. It illustrates exactly what I'm trying to do.
I've solved the problem. The problem was that I had too much divs in between the outer and children divs. (Yes I know I should have said that since the beginning)

Comment: In this fiddle, transition is only applied in expandedSection. When you rollback you will not get the transition. And I have a question, why this is the correct answer? I don't see any changes, only removing classes in a working code....

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, I just thought the fiddle got a bit more of the concept I was trying to explain. I may have misunderstood your fiddle. I probably have. I'm working right now, but I promise this afternoon I will review both answers and give the point to whichever I find more correct.
I just don't have much time to review them deeply right now and I thought the fiddle on this one illustated more my problem. However, you both guys helped me, and I am thankful for that.

Comment: No, I am not envy because the correct answer, so our answers are identically, the only differences that's I preserve all your classnames and @RameezRami remove some of them. But the answer is the same: your code works in a simply scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLuc3fht/

If you make click on the body you can view the transition. I've only added

```
 html , body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Okay I found the problem. I'm going to give you the answer since you helped making me see that it should work and my HTML structure was breaking it. I'm also going to post what was the actual problem so anybody can find it for future reference.

Comment: You need to share all the code, because the fiddle is an invent by me. Sure your problem is in another place different than the code you are sharing.

Comment: I'm going to take some time though, I can't share the actual code. I'm going to make a jsfiddle for this question's sake, but I'm going to take some time. I'll notify you when I do it :)

Comment: Ok, no problem! I've been waiting here